# I want to run my extra-addons module in dockerized odoo container

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo

I have installed Docker in my system with **odoo:latest** and **postgres:latest** as a container, and i can successfully start & stop my odoo service.

But the problem is i can only see the base odoo modules in it instead i want to run my own created modules along with the base modules in the dockerized odoo.

I have searched many links but but failed to understand.

**What should i do to run my own modules ?**

Please help me with all the steps to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know Odoo but are modules = addons? You can easily mount them (see documentation on docker hub): Mount custom addons: 1. start postgres, 2. Create /path/to/extra-addons and put your modules in it on your host. 3. mount modules in odoo container: `$ docker run -v /path/to/addons:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo`

Comment: yes i mean modules = addons

Comment: what does /path/to/addons specify ?
Where can i get it

Comment: Just create it on your host machine. What OS are you working on? On linux it can be something like /home/user/my-folder/addons/ on mac osx it can be something like /users/myuser/my-folder/addons.. You can create the folder by yourself and you can choose the name by yourself. You just have to specify the path of the folder you've created in the docker run command.

Comment: Done everything you said but still i'm not able to install my custom addons

Comment: what does `docker logs container-name` tell?

Comment: 'docker logs odoo
2017-08-30 06:49:47,290 1 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0-20170815
2017-08-30 06:49:47,290 1 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
2017-08-30 06:49:47,291 1 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/10.0', u'/mnt/extra-addons', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons']
2017-08-30 06:49:47,291 1 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@172.17.0.2:5432
2017-08-30 06:49:47,306 1 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2017-08-30 06:49,563 1 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres'

Comment: Can you show me your docker run command and also give me the full path of the folder where you have stored your addons.

Comment: You can access your docker container and check the folder `/mnt/extra-addons`.

Comment: docker run -v /home/ujjwal/Downloads/hr/:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo

Comment: Go inside the container and check if `/mnt/extra-addons` is getting the correct files or not?

Comment: Yes, Inside the container '/mnt/extra-addons' it contains my mounted files...
How can i install & use them ?

Comment: I'm not getting the files inside that folder in docker, why?

Comment: Follow the below answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The solution to this problem has been resolved as-**

Firstly i mounted my local folder which contains my extra-addons by the command-

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/your/local/folder:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

> Then check weather your local folder is mounted on the odoo container
> or not by-

```
$ docker exec -u root -it odoo /bin/bash
```

After logging-

```
$ ls /mnt/extra-addons
```

You should see your files which were present in your **local/folder**.
Now, its done just **restart** your docker odoo server

> To stop-

```
$ sudo docker stop db
$ sudo docker stop odoo
$ sudo service docker stop
```

> To Start-

```
$ sudo service docker start
$ sudo docker start db
$ sudo docker start -a odoo
```

**Now you can install your modules from the app.**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to mount a folder from your host machine to the docker...  go to docker hub and in the odoo image you will find how to mount your custom modules

Comment: Mounting has been done already, i just want to know how can i install my custom addons to in docker-odoo.

Comment: @UjjwalSinghBaghel please let me know if you found a answer to that

Comment: @anandtripathi yes, I found my answer and its posted above. You can refer it, let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: @UjjwalSinghBaghel you have mounted your local folder so that is in the filesystem of host, I want to dockerized my addons also like in image.

Comment: @anandtripathi when you pull the Odoo image in docker container the addons is mounted by-default there!